# Moving cursor position by offset value

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

```
$text->SetCursor( position );
```

This is used to move cursor at the given position.

Is there any way that I can move the cursor by a given offset value?

Thanks,

Comment: What Perl module are you using?

Comment: i am using perl 5.12 and using perl tk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the [correct position descriptor](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M7); they support a little language of their own. For example, the string `insert + 1 char` describes the location one character further on than the insertion point (`insert` is a special kind of mark that represents where text will be inserted and is where the caret is located when focus is in the text widget).